# Linear system corresponding to a pendulum with friction: does the pendulum stop?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the following simple linear system, which is said to correspond to a pendulum with friction:

$$\dot{x_1} = x_2, \quad \dot{x_2} = -x_1 - x_2.$$

> Find the critical points of the system and determine their type.

Obviously the only critical point is $(0,0)$; we find that the eigenvalues associated to the linearization there have negative real part, so that $(0,0)$ is a sink.

> Draw the phase portrait of the system in the $(x_1,x_2)$-plane.

It looks like some skewed spiral.

> Will the pendulum ever stop?

This is what's giving me trouble. I want to say that no, the pendulum won't ever stop, since in general the initial value problem $\dot{x} = Ax$, $x(0) = x_0$ has a unique solution defined for all time, so that the only way for the pendulum to stop is to have $x(0) = 0$, that is, to never actually move. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very good. You could be a bit more explicit and give the solution to show that the time to reach 0 is infinite, but what you've put is enough to satisfy me.

For speed, you only need to compare the trace and the determinant of a 2x2 matrix to classify the critical points https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_dynamical_system

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, the solution $e^{At}x_0$ shows that it takes infinite time to reach $0$.